# echo dentro de $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>
   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve SUPERVISÃO?</li>
   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;'id='supervisaoS'>X</label></li>
   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='supervisaoN'>X</label></li>
</ul>
```

**PHP imprimindo JavaScript**:

```
echo
$celulasReuniao->getSupervisao() == "s" 
    ? "<script>$('#supervisaoS').css('visibility','visible')</script>" 
    : "<script>$('#supervisaoN').css('visibility','visible')</script>"
;
```

**O problema**:

Esse código está dentro de uma chamada `$.ajax`:

```
$("#celPastor").on("click", function () {

    if ( checkRadioPeriodo() == false ) return false;
    if ( checkRadioOrdenacao() == false ) return false;

    $.ajax({
        url: "_scripts/_php/_buscas/relatorioCelulas.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            ordenacao: $("[name='ordenacao']:checked").val(),
            celPastor: "",
            periodo  : $("[name='periodo']:checked").val(),
            idPastor : null
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#celPastor").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#imgCarregando").css("visibility", "visible");
        },
        success: function (result) {

            $("#celPastor").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#imgCarregando").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".resposta").html(result);

        }
    });

})
```

Dessa forma, toda vez que faço um echo aqui, o `$.ajax` reclama e não deixa prosseguir. Porém essa **validação** é *necessária* para *marcar* o **X** no campo **certo**.

Existe algum recurso para isso?

Ou estou fazendo errado?

**Saída do console:**

```
<script>$('#supervisaoS').css('visibility','visible')</script><script>$('#supervisaoN').css('visibility','visible')</script><script>$('#supervisaoN').css('visibility','visible')</script><script>$('#supervisaoN').css('visibility','visible')</script>"\t\r\n    <div class='relatorio'>\r\n\t\r\n\t\t<img src='_imgs\/gceu.png' \/> <h1>Relat\u00f3rio Mensal<\/h1>\r\n\t\t<br \/><br \/><div>\t\r\n\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Gc\u00e9u<\/label> : C\u00e9lula 1<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;' class='backCinza'><label class='labelPequeno'>Supervisor de Setor<\/label> : Jonas<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>L\u00edder<\/label> : Cleonice<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Auxiliar<\/label> : Cleonice<\/li>\r\n\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Dias que acontece<\/label> : Ter\u00e7a<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Membros Ativos<\/label> : 1<\/li>\r\n\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t<br \/>\t<ul class='vertical'><li><h3 class='hCentralizado'>Reuni\u00f5es<\/h3><\/li><\/ul><div class='reunioesCelulas'>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Data<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Membros<br \/>Comprometidos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Visitantes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Criancas<br \/>0-10 anos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Total<br \/>Presentes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Oferta<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Discipulado<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>GE's<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse dadosRel'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>15\/01\/2019<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>20<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>3<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>2<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>25<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>  : R$ 30,45<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes no Domingo<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes na Semana<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:20%;' class='backCinza'>Decis\u00f5es<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>2<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<br \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:79.05%'>QUEST\u00d5ES COMPLEMENTARES<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>SIM<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>N\u00c3O<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve Evangelismo nas proximidades do GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve dia de Jejum coletivo pelo GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve SUPERVIS\u00c3O?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;'id='supervisaoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='supervisaoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>Observa\u00e7\u00f5es:<br \/><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Data<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Membros<br \/>Comprometidos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Visitantes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Criancas<br \/>0-10 anos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Total<br \/>Presentes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Oferta<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Discipulado<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>GE's<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse dadosRel'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>01\/02\/2019<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>10<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>2<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>2<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>14<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>  : R$ 22,65<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>1<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes no Domingo<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes na Semana<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:20%;' class='backCinza'>Decis\u00f5es<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>6<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<br \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:79.05%'>QUEST\u00d5ES COMPLEMENTARES<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>SIM<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>N\u00c3O<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve Evangelismo nas proximidades do GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve dia de Jejum coletivo pelo GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve SUPERVIS\u00c3O?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;'id='supervisaoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='supervisaoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>Observa\u00e7\u00f5es:<br \/><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Data<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Membros<br \/>Comprometidos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Visitantes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Criancas<br \/>0-10 anos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Total<br \/>Presentes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Oferta<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Discipulado<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>GE's<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse dadosRel'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>03\/02\/2019<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>20<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>5<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>9<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>34<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>  : R$ 55,33<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>1<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes no Domingo<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes na Semana<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:20%;' class='backCinza'>Decis\u00f5es<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>3<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<br \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:79.05%'>QUEST\u00d5ES COMPLEMENTARES<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>SIM<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>N\u00c3O<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve Evangelismo nas proximidades do GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve dia de Jejum coletivo pelo GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve SUPERVIS\u00c3O?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;'id='supervisaoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='supervisaoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>Observa\u00e7\u00f5es:<br \/><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/div><ul class=\"resumo\">  <li><i>Totais no per\u00eddo de 15 dias para o Gc\u00e9u : C\u00e9lula 1<\/i><\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Visitas<\/label> : 10<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Crian\u00e7as<\/label> : 13<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Presentes<\/label> : 50<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Discipulados<\/label> : 2<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Oferta<\/label> : R$ 108,43<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Descisoes<\/label> : 11<\/li><\/ul><hr noshade=\"noshade\" width=\"100%\" size=\"5px\" \/><br \/>\t\r\n\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Gc\u00e9u<\/label> : Celula 2<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;' class='backCinza'><label class='labelPequeno'>Supervisor de Setor<\/label> : Jonas<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>L\u00edder<\/label> : Carlos<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Auxiliar<\/label> : Carlos<\/li>\r\n\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Dias que acontece<\/label> : Segunda<\/li>\r\n\t\t   <li style='text-align: left;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Membros Ativos<\/label> : 1<\/li>\r\n\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t<br \/>\t<ul class='vertical'><li><h3 class='hCentralizado'>Reuni\u00f5es<\/h3><\/li><\/ul><div class='reunioesCelulas'>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Data<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Membros<br \/>Comprometidos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Visitantes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Criancas<br \/>0-10 anos<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Total<br \/>Presentes<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Oferta<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>Discipulado<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li><label>GE's<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios minhaClasse dadosRel'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>31\/01\/2019<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>5<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>2<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>1<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>8<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>  : R$ 78,39<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>1<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes no Domingo<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:23.5%;' class='backCinza'>Presentes na Semana<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado backCinza' style='width:20%;' class='backCinza'>Decis\u00f5es<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%;'>0<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<br \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios backCinza'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:79.05%'>QUEST\u00d5ES COMPLEMENTARES<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>SIM<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'>N\u00c3O<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve Evangelismo nas proximidades do GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='evangelismoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve dia de Jejum coletivo pelo GCEU?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='jejumN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve SUPERVIS\u00c3O?<\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;'id='supervisaoS'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='supervisaoN'>X<\/label><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul class='border'>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   <li>Observa\u00e7\u00f5es:<br \/><\/li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/div><ul class=\"resumo\">  <li><i>Totais no per\u00eddo de 15 dias para o Gc\u00e9u : Celula 2<\/i><\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Visitas<\/label> : 2<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Crian\u00e7as<\/label> : 1<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Presentes<\/label> : 5<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Discipulados<\/label> : 1<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Oferta<\/label> : R$ 78,39<\/li>  <li><label class=\"labelPequeno\">Descisoes<\/label> : 0<\/li><\/ul><hr noshade=\"noshade\" width=\"100%\" size=\"5px\" \/><br \/><\/div>"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é "ele reclama"?

Comment: Este "echo", você esta fazendo dentro de "data"?

Comment: Ao usar `dataType: "json",` vc está esperando um JSON como retorno do `relatorioCelulas.php`... Qual seria esse JSON?

Comment: exatamente isso: o json está sendo impresso no console. O código está parando parando a exibição no browser por conta do echo. Ou seja, a exibição só acontece no console.

Comment: adicionei a saída na pergunta mas está grande

Comment: Coloca o Ajax completo. Tá meio confuso de entender.

Comment: se eu retiro o echo, o código a página aparece mas, em consequência disso os visible's não funcionam

Comment: feito, está na pergunta já!

Comment: Essa "saída no console" que vc colocou é o valor de `result`?

Comment: não sei dizer, mas adicionei uma print do console à pergunta. Mas acho que é sim pois é o que sai lá né?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89390/discussion-between-sam-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: eu sei que em saídas ajax NÃO pode haver echos. Mas aqui está sendo necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
if ( $celulasReuniao->getSupervisao() == "s" ) {
    $echoSupervisao = "
       <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: visible;'id='supervisaoS'>X</label></li>
       <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;' id='supervisaoN'>X</label></li>";
} else {
    $echoSupervisao = "
       <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: hidden;'id='supervisaoS'>X</label></li>
       <li class='centralizado' style='width:10%; border-left: .1px solid rgb(0,0,0);'><label style='visibility: visible;' id='supervisaoN'>X</label></li>";
}


<ul class='border ulHRelatorios'>
   <li style='text-align: left; width:79.05%'>Houve SUPERVISÃO?</li>
   " . $echoSupervisao . "
</ul>
```